# how can I make the uiviewcontroller visible only once during first run of the app (e.g. tutorial)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm creating an iOS `swift` app and I want to show tutorial screen when user runs the app for the very first time. Later on, with each run of the app the tutorial should be hidden and another view controller should be visible as a starting point. So far my storyboard looks like this:

[image]

It contains two screens of tutorial (1st and last) and tab bar (which is a main window of my app).

As for now, in storyboard I chose the tab bar to be an initial view controller:

[image]

And with that approach the tutorial screen is never seen. How can I show it only once on first launch app and then skip it each time user opens the app?

Comment: ok, thanks for the suggestion! But how can I decide whether to show the screen or not based on the bool flag? From which place should I do it?

Comment: You could check in your app delegate, and then set the root view controller there.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik can you show me an example of the code that I could use? I tried to use: `let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tutorialFirst")
        self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)` but the screen didn't change for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of `AppDelegate` check for `NSUserDefaults` value like this way.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if defaults.objectForKey("isFirstTime") == nil {
         defaults.setObject("No", forKey:"isFirstTime")
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil) //Write your storyboard name
         let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
         self.window.rootViewController = viewController 
         self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

**Note:** I have created the object of `ViewController` you need to create the object of your FirstPage tutorial screen after that assign it to the `rootViewController`.

Comment: Hm, I'm getting error here: `let viewController = self.storyboard?` that says `Value of type 'AppDeleage' has no member 'storyboard'

Comment: you no need to call `defaults.synchronize`, i think

Comment: @LalKrishna Yes now we don't need to call synchronize method every you update or set value in UserDefaults it will automatically synchronize

Answer (score 3):

For swift 4 make these changes.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if defaults.object(forKey: "isFirstTime") == nil {
    defaults.set("No", forKey:"isFirstTime")
    defaults.synchronize()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplified Swift 4 version of this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39353299/1565913

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didSee") {
         UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didSee")

         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
         let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController")
         self.window?.rootViewController = viewController 
         self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this is `Scene Delegate`

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "introLaunched") == false{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "introLaunched")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "IntroScreenViewController") as! IntroScreenViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    } else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    }
}
```