# Showing different view controllers depending on push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

How do you show difference between 2 view controllers at the start of an application based on whether push notifications are enabled? I have the following code but the screen goes black for awhile after the lauch storyboard and is too slow.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {

        let current =  UNUserNotificationCenter.current();

        current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler:
        {
            (settings) in

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined
            {
                // self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let aViewController = AViewController();

                self.window?.rootViewController = aViewController;

                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
            }
            else
            {
                // self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let bViewController = BViewController();

                self.window?.rootViewController = bViewController;

                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
            }
        });

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }
```

Can I put this code elsewhere? Can I extend the launch screen while it waits? Thanks.

Comment: are this two controllers are in storyboard?

Comment: no they are programmatic. i found a better way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352907/how-can-i-make-the-uiviewcontroller-visible-only-once-during-first-run-of-the-ap

Comment: if your completion handler is taking too much time to detect isNotification Enabled or Disabled try checking simple bool **UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications** , Though you also do not need to assign Frame to **self.window** just set root controller as **self.window?.rootViewController = bViewController**

Comment: that is deprecated