# Skip initial view controller on Second launch of App in swift 4 / Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to skip my Initial View Controller if the user has already opened app earlier. I got the value in Bool whether user has logged in already or not. 
Here is my Code : If Initial launch is true (user is launching for first time), go to Login ViewController. else continue as usual.
I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4

```
if(initialLaunch == true)
{
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "backrollseague", sender: self)
}
```

here is my story board:
[image]

I tried this part many times... But Its not working. Please help.

Comment: Where you change the boolean value?

Comment: where are you writing this code means in which controller

Comment: there should no back segue use dismiss or unwind segue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a user is logged in and if not redirect to the login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334055/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-logged-in-and-if-not-redirect-to-the-login-screen)

Comment: @Kerberos Boolean value Iam checking from database and changing. That is working properly. But seague is not working

Comment: @RahulGUsai As you see, the First View that'll work by default is NOT Login page. So Iam writing this code in ViewdidLoad of that Page.(Page with TableView)

Comment: @Adeel In that, they are checking programmatically, Since I am using storyboards for seague, I couldn't do that

Comment: then consider @Sh_Khan answer it is what you want

Comment: @Ashique you however have to check the condition programatically since it is not possible in the interface builder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I make the uiviewcontroller visible only once during first run of the app (e.g. tutorial)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352907/how-can-i-make-the-uiviewcontroller-visible-only-once-during-first-run-of-the-ap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "userExists")
{
    let stor = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let homeView = stor.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeView")
    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeView)
    nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = nav

}
```

Comment: Sir, last line should be `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() `. Do you agree ?